# Is it possbile in ASP.NET to deny access to a number of directories using single directive?

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config, authorization

Is it possible to deny access not only per directory using directive `<location>` but a to a number of directories at one time?

Or I have to use every time `<location>` for each directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that this is possible using the location tags. It of course applies to all subdirectories, but I don't think that's what you're referring to.

You could of course write your own handler, or have a page base class that all pages you want to protect inherit from.